# Installed bitcoin-qt and Tor, allowed firewall, Tor connects, but Bitcoin doesn't

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, tor

I did these things but Bitcoin still says 0 connections. What's the problem?

1. Windows 7 32bit. Installed bitcoin-qt
2. Installed Tor Browser bundle
3. I allowed all local outbound connections in my firwall (remote connections allowed only for Tor, for bitcion they're forbidden).
4. Run bitcoin.exe and enabled SOCKS proxy 127.0.0.1 on port 9050.
5. Exit bitcoin.exe, run Tor Vidalia, wait till it say "Connected to Tor"
6. Run bitcoin-qt.exe
7. Wait, wait, wait... 0 connections. In Resource Monitor I see only Tor connects to the internet. Bitcoin doesn't connect anywhere.

Please help.

Comment: Can you try changing the SOCKS proxy port to 9150 and disabling listening? Is this a recent version of TBB?

Comment: Check your torrc file -- look in the browser bundle directory in Data/Tor/. It is a textfile full of configurations and it should say which is the correct port to use.  At some point they apparently changed it from 9150 to 9050 (or the other way around).  Quit vidalia/stop tor before changing anything there, then restart.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Core works fine with Tor. There is a current setup guide in [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/how-can-i-setup-bitcoin-to-be-anonymous-with-tor). The only thing that you may need to adjust is if your current Windows setup uses port 9150 
(instead of port 9050) for the Tor Socks5 proxy.